# open android own launcher from my application

Tags: android, launcher, homescreen, package-managers

hi Its been 2 days looking for this simple problem. I want to launch Android own launcher from my application EVEN if its not set as default.

```
   final PackageManager packageManager=getPackageManager();
   Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.launcher");
```

this return null for Android own launcher but if I try custom launcher is give me successfully

Comment: I'm developing custom home screen, and i want to launch the default home when required, and I'm facing above same issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the solution, after investigating source code of [getLaunchIntentForPackage](http://www.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java&q=getLaunchIntentForPackage&type=cs&l=). As per documentation,

> The current implementation will look first for a main activity in the
>   category CATEGORY_INFO, next for a main activity in the category
>   CATEGORY_LAUNCHER, or return null if neither are found.

So, the function don't look for CATEGORY_HOME, i rewrote it in following way, it worked perfectly.

```
Intent intentToResolve = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intentToResolve.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intentToResolve.setPackage("com.android.launcher");
ResolveInfo ri = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intentToResolve, 0);
if (ri != null) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(intentToResolve);
    intent.setClassName(ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, ri.activityInfo.name);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I tried using the same for "com.android.phone" but for some reason it doesn't work. Any inputs?

Comment: this takes me to the home screen instead of the application launcher screen

Comment: I'm having the same issue as @13hsoj where ri is always null

Comment: @Bruce are you trying it for com.android.phone or for com.android.launcher

Comment: where should this code be added? can you please mention the class name also?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the default `Google Android Launcher` being installed on your device? If not, then it's truly `NULL`.

Comment: I am trying this on emulator and for mobile I've tried "com.sonyericsson.home" on my Xperia Arc but it give me force close error doesn't even throw any exception.