# How to redirect User to default launcher in an android app?

Tags: android, android-activity, launcher, homescreen

It's been now a long time since I try to figure out how to develop a android unlock screen app working with an NFC authentication. I am working with a Nexus S.
After several researches on the Internet, I came to the conclusion that replacing the lock screen as a third party app is just not supported right now and that we need to modify the platform to do a decent implementation.

This is the reason why I developed an home screen app that give the illusion of an unlockscreen app. But my problem is that I would like to be redirect to the default laucher at the end of the procedure.

I first tried with the code below but the problem is that I will have the choice between the default home screen and my new app

```
Intent goHome = new Intent();
i.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
i.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
startActivity(goHome);
```

So I then I tried with the code below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Intent goHome = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
goHome.setClassName("com.android.launcher", "com.android.launcher.Launcher");
startActivity(goHome);
```

I get the following logCat

> Unable to find explicit activity class ( com.android.launcher.laucher)

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work? Is it the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
goHome.setClassName("com.android.launcher", "com.android.launcher2.Launcher");
```

Comment: @ethan_liou  i m getting error 05-11 10:38:26.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6728): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 10:38:26.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6728): Process: com.example.lockapplication, PID: 6728
05-11 10:38:26.300: E/AndroidRuntime(6728): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
    List<ResolveInfo> lst = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
    if (lst != null) {
       for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : lst) {
           try {
           Intent home = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
           home.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
           home.setClassName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
           startActivity(home);
           break;
           } catch (Throwable t) {
               t.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was not upvoted before I did but this is the only solution that works for me. Kudos to you @user1135940 !

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a Samsung device, the following code worked for me:

```
Intent goHome = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        goHome.setClassName("com.sec.android.app.launcher", "com.android.launcher2.Launcher");
        startActivity(goHome);
```