# Open the phone default launcher when clicking a button

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to open the phone default launcher, where all the phone's applications are displayed, whenever i click my button.

I've tried to look up for an answer but i couldn't find one,
Is that even possible?
Maybe by passing a category to an intent?

Comment: where all the apps are

Comment: my question is why do you want to do that?

Comment: i want to change the wallpaper and open the application laucnher whenever my button clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the Menu, (as per original question):

Use Activity.[openOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29)() method in the `OnClickListener` of the button

**Edit**:
Edited question as per OP's comments to open launcher, please refer solution at

[How to redirect User to default launcher in an android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787658/how-to-redirect-user-to-default-launcher-in-an-android-app)

Comment: i mean the menu of the SystemUI,where all the apps are

Comment: Ok, for that please check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18804002/2982225)

Comment: Please check [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9787658/2982225). Hope it helps. This is not called a menu, it's called the default Launcher application.

Comment: thank you that got me to something,but when i launch the ".Launcher" class it just get me to the Main Screen and not to the default Launcher Application

Comment: Try the code samples from [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16483596/2982225).