# Intent to start All Apps activity

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Launch Home Screen Programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756835/how-to-launch-home-screen-programmatically-in-android)

Is there an Intent I can prepare that will start the "All Apps" activity (aka app launcher)?

I looked in LogCat and ActivityManager isn't logging an Intent when I click on the icon from the home screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at some copies of the Launcher, it doesn't look like there is an Intent you can use to open the default app launcher directly. You can see one copy of the source at https://github.com/cscott/android-launcher2/blob/master/src/com/android/launcher2/Launcher.java: the reference code is at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2, but doesn't have the convenient browsing interface any more.

There is an `mAllAppsButton` that shows the app selection screen, but it doesn't appear to be tied to any `Intent`, just to an internal click handler. You may be out of luck.

Comment: I had assumed there was no Intent for it, especially since OEM's can create their own Launcher activity.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```