# How to send application to all app screen

Tags: android

I want to send intent from any application to **all apps screen**. For your reference regarding all app screen [**All app screen example**](http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html). I am not able to find any help regarding this intent. Any help will be appreciated.[image]

When i click cancel from any dialog box it should exit application and user must land on the all apps screen.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481369/intent-to-start-all-apps-activity

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643729/launch-launcher-app-drawer-from-an-application

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Comment: It won't help, @iaindownie. Your code shows the home screen, not what he wants, the drawer (all apps)