# Android Instantiate a Dummy PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have an Android library that has a `Service` that creates a `Notification`. From what I understand `Notification` must have a `contentIntent` (`PendingIntent`) set or a runtime exception will be thrown.

The problem is that I want users to be able to use this `Service` as is, or extend it, so that they can set the `PendingIntent` themselves through a callback during the creation of the `Notification`. However, if they choose not to do this, I need to set the `PendingIntent` to something so that there is no exception. Is there any way to create a dummy `PendingIntent` that just acts as a fill-in?

Here's an example of the code from the `createNotification` method:

```
PendingIntent p;
if(getPendingIntentCallback != null) {
    p = getPendingIntentCallback.getPendingIntent();
}
else {
    p = ?;
}
notification.contentIntent = p;
```

Comment: What do you want the behavior to be if the user clicks a notification that does not have an intent attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A notification needs to have some sort of action associated with it.  You have to tell android what to do when a app user clicks the notification.  Letting your library fail if no contentIntent has been defined will let your library user know that they have missed a very important step.

You could check for the pending intent before creating your notification.

```
if(getPendingIntentCallback != null) {
    p = getPendingIntentCallback.getPendingIntent();
    // create a notification

}
else {
    //don't create a notification
    Log.d("Notification", "Your notification was not created because no pending intent was found");
}
```

Or to answer the question you asked, you could create a dummy pending intent that performs some arbitrary action like going to the home screen.

See this thread:
[How to Launch Home Screen Programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756835/how-to-launch-home-screen-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: I'll give you the answer because you got me started on the right train of thought. I'm going to set the `Intent` to my service and put the notification id in it as an extra, and then just cancel the notification in `onStartCommand`

Answer (score 8):

```
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("DoNothing"), 0);
```

This worked for me. It will launch a broacast for a "DoNothing" action. I hope nobody will listen for a "DoNothing" broadcast and do something as a reaction to it. But if you prefer you can construct something more exotic.
Note: I'm using this just as a temporary placeholder. I will substitute it with something more useful for the user as I will advance in my application development.

Comment: This is a nice answer for someone generalizing the original question. In my case I'm defining a set of Notification actions, most of which do *something* through a broadcast or getActivity, but the user needs to be reminded the have the option to "do nothing" in my use case.