# Switching between two activities

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-stack

Imagine that you have 2 activitie - A and B. You're starting B from A. In B you have a task. And if task is completed you want to go back to A when back key pressed if not you want to dismiss the whole application. But after dissmissing you can resume B from recent apps menu. And if after that you need the same behavior of back key.

So I want to dismiss just one activity or the whole app (but with resume possibility). Is there any way to achive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ActivityB` override `onBackPressed()` and if the task is completed, just call `super.onBackPressed()` which will finish `ActivityB` and return to `ActivityA`. Otherwise, to **dismiss the whole app** just use `moveTaskToBack()` and don't call `super.onBackPressed()`. When the user returns to the app, `ActivityB` will be shown (since it has not yet been finished).

Comment: Yes, but if moveTaskToBack() is called then when task will complete and I'll press back key the whole application still will be dismissed. And there is no way to move activity B to the front of the stack as far as I know.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. If your activity stack contains `ActivityA->ActivityB` and you move this task to the background, then bring it back to the foreground, you still have `ActivityA->ActivityB` with `ActivityB` in front. Please explain more what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss an Activity, you can call its finish() method. And for dismissing the whole application, try launching an Intent for the Home Activity.
Take a look to this:
[How to Launch Home Screen Programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756835/how-to-launch-home-screen-programmatically-in-android)